# Execute Linux nodejs command line in Java

Tags: java, linux, node.js, bower

I am using [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) in my project to run [bower](http://bower.io/) command in OS (Linux and windows), this working great in windows but in Linux can't find the command "bower" and thank you for helping.

```
    String command="bower --allow-root";
    CommandLine commandline = null;
    if (isWindows()) {
        commandline = new CommandLine("cmd");
        commandline.addArguments(new String[] { "/c", command }, false);
    }
    if (isUnix()) {
        commandline = new CommandLine("/bin/bash");
        commandline.addArguments(new String[] { "-c", command }, false);
    }
    ExecuteCommandResponse executeCommandResponse = new ExecuteCommandResponse();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
    exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    exec.setWorkingDirectory(workingDirectory);
    try {
        exec.execute(commandline);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: what happens, when you execute `bower help` from command line (your bash shell)?

Comment: absolutely it works in terminal but when I called from Java not founding it.

Comment: 1."your terminal" is "/bin/bash"? 2. what when you do `bash -c 'bower --allow-root'`?

Comment: it works `# bash -c 'bower --allow-root'
Usage:
    bower <command> [<args>] [<options>] .....
`

Comment: I mean in terminal I make SSH to my server and run the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bower is JavaScript file so the bash can't run it. Correct code

```
if (isUnix()) {
    commandline = new CommandLine("/usr/local/bin/node");
    commandline.addArguments(new String[] { "/usr/local/bin/bower","--allow-root"}, false);
}
```